# How to change spinner height

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

Am creating two spinners, date and numeric, dynamically to a dialog in codenameone. Is there a way I could be able to change spinner height, both date and numeric?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend migrating to [Picker](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html) which provides a more native on device experience.

You can use the theme to style the padding of the elements within the spinner to make them take up more/less space.

Comment: Ok, although for the spinner I have tried the  best of styling but haven't been able to change default size. Thank you.

Comment: Which UIID did you customize? Did you customize `SpinnerRenderer`?